# Is there a less colloquial term for the phenomenon known as "brain zaps"?

Tags: neuroscience, abnormal-psychology, terminology, depression, psychopharmacology

There is an unpleasant phenomenon, colloquially known as "brain zaps".  It is generally associated with withdrawal from antidepressants, but this isn't always the trigger - I sometimes have it even though I've taken my mess that day.

I don't like referring to something so unpleasant and uncomfortable by such a silly name.  Is there a proper medical term for this phenomenon?

Comment: [Antidepressant discontinuation syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antidepressant_discontinuation_syndrome) might be what you're looking for. It is also known as SSRI withdrawal. Other colloquial (yet less-silly) terms for them would be 'head shocks' or 'electrical shocks'.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**
Brain zaps are a colloquial term for certain symptoms of antidepressant discontinuation syndrome.

**Background**
'**[Brain zaps](http://www.anxietycentre.com/anxiety-symptoms/brain-zaps.shtml)**' are associated with sudden shakes, or vibrations, tremors, jolts, electric shocks, or 'zaps' of the head and/or brain. As SydneyMaples rightfully commented, these are scientifically recognized as symptoms of

> [**Antidepressant discontinuation syndrome**, or **Antidepressant withdrawal syndrome**](http://www.webmd.com/depression/guide/withdrawal-from-antidepressants)

Withdrawal from a wide range of [antidepressants](http://www.webmd.com/depression/guide/depression-medications-antidepressants), including the [tricyclic antidepressants](https://www.drugs.com/drug-class/tricyclic-antidepressants.html) (TCAs), [monoamine oxidase inhibitors](http://www.medicinenet.com/mao_inhibitors-oral/article.htm) (MAOIs) and [selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/depression/in-depth/ssris/art-20044825) (SSRIs) can produce somatic and psychological distress, influenza-like syndromes, gastrointestinal adverse effects, arrhythmias, anxiety, sleep disturbances, movement disorders, mania or hypomania, panic attacks and delirium [(Lejoyeux *et al*., 1996)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.2165/00023210-199605040-00006).

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Lejoyeux *et al*. CNS Drugs (1996); **5**(4): 278–92](https://link.springer.com/article/10.2165/00023210-199605040-00006)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> I don't like referring to something so unpleasant and uncomfortable by such a silly name. Is there a proper medical term for this phenomenon?

In the literature, they're referred to as **shock-like paresthesias** and less commonly, **Lhermitte's sign** (pronounced Ler-meets).

However, the phenomenology of Lhermitte's sign is a little bit different to brain zaps and is typically seen in multiple sclerosis.

From **[The SSRI discontinuation syndrome](https://doi.org/10.1177/026988119801200311)**:

$
\require{color}
\hspace{0.5cm}Sensory\text{ }abnormalities.\text{These include paraesthesia (i.e.}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{tingling) and numbness, also described with TCA discon-}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{tinuation but less prominent, and brief ’electric shock-like’}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{sensations which appear unique to SSRI and venlafaxine}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{termination (Louie et al., 1996). The shocks may be}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{experienced as ’electrical sensations’ (Rosenstock, 1996)}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{running through the head, upper body, arms or legs or as}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{intense internal sensations within the head, for example a}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{’slamming’ within the head (Mallya et al., 1993), a ’whooshing}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{noise’ or a ’rush’ one could ’almost hear’ (Berlin, 1996).}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{Sometimes they are exacerbated by movement, particularly of}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{the head, and are associated with brief bursts of dizziness}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{(Frost and Lal, 1995). Ellison’s (1993) description of bursts of}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{dizziness as a ’jolt’, ’rush’, ’shock’, or ’buzz’ also suggests an}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{overlap between shocks and dizziness.} \colorbox{yellow}{Coupland et al. (1996)}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\colorbox{yellow}{regarded the shocks as a severe form of paraesthesia and}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\colorbox{yellow}{emphasized that they were distinct from anything patients had}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\colorbox{yellow}{experienced before.}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{Shocks have occurred following discontinuation from}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{sertraline (Rosenstock, 1996), paroxetine (Frost and Lal,}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{1995; Dominguez and Goodnick, 1996), fluoxetine (Berlin,}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{1996) and fluvoxamine (Mallya et al., 1993).} \colorbox{yellow}{Reeves and}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\colorbox{yellow}{Pinkofsky (1996) reported a paroxetine discontinuation}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\colorbox{yellow}{reaction in which shocks were consistently elicited by neck}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\colorbox{yellow}{flexion. They proposed that the sensations constituted}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\colorbox{yellow}{Lhermitte’s sign i.e. a neurological sign that usually indicates}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}\colorbox{yellow}{spinal cord disease.}\\
$